# Virtual function output?

Tags: c++

I was just doing some stuff and wrote this program. I got the following output. I know that function resolution happens at run time while binding of the variable takes place during compile time, but what I could not understand was the first output I got (`this->n`). Can anyone explain this to me?

```
    # include <iostream>
    # include <stdio.h>
    # include <conio.h>

    using namespace std;

    class A
    {
      int n;      
      public:
      virtual void Fun1(int no=10)
       {
         int n=no;        
         cout<<"A::Fun1() "<<n <<"\n";
       }
    };

    class B :public A
    {
     int n;      
     public:
     virtual void Fun1(int no=20)
     {
      int n=no;        
      cout<<"B::Fun1() " << this->n << "\n"; // WHY SO ? gives B::Fun1() 40
      cout<<"B::Fun1() " << n << "\n";
     }
    };

    int main()
    {
     B b;
     A &a =b;
     a.Fun1();
     A a1=b;
     a1.Fun1();
     getch();
     return 0;
    }
```

The output I got was

```
    B::Fun1() 40
    B::Fun1() 10
    A::Fun1() 10
```

Comment: Your class data members are uninitialized; you could get _any_ value from them.

Comment: You're slicing the object with `A a1=b;`. This is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first output, `this->n` refers to the member variable `B::n`, which you never initialise - this could print anything.

For the second, `n` refers to the local variable `n`, which you initialise with the function argument. Since default arguments are provided by the caller, and you're calling the function via a reference to `A`, you get the default value specified in `A::Fun1`, not the one in `B::Fun1`. If you were to call `b.Fun1()`, then it would print `B::Fun1() 20`.

For the third, you've "sliced" the `B` object, giving an object of type `A`, hence the call to `A::Fun1`.

Answer (score 3):

Your member variable `B::n` is not being initialized anywhere. You're lucky you got a reasonable value at all, it could have been anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your B::n is uninitialized I get this when I run the code.

B::Fun1() -858993460
B::Fun1() 10
A::Fun1() 10